# CSS3 Transition Slide Down/Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

```
.header {
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:50px;
        z-index:2
}    
.menu ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
        -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .menu ul.is-visible {
        -webkit-transform:translateY(50px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(50px);
        transform:translateY(50px)
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

The above is the CSS I use to toggle a menu open/close using a transition element for a sliding down/up effect.

Currently the menu slides from the top of the header; is it possible for it to slide from the bottom of the header which is 50px from the top?

I'm still trying to learn how to use transition, so any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/5drXq/)

You didn't provide your markup, so I had to guess.  Basically, if you wrap the li text in a span and give it a background color to match the color of the header (navigation bar), you can obscure the menu as it drops into place.

Also, I didn't bother with the floating and absolute positioning.  Again, I don't have the benefit of seeing your actual markup, but it was unneeded to accomplish this particular layout.

```css
header {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
    color: yellowgreen;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul.menu > li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    width: 150px;
}
li span {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.menu > li > a {
    color: white;
}
li > ul {
    background-color: white;
    color: yellowgreen;
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-200%);
    -moz-transform:translateY(-200%);
    transform:translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
li > ul > li {
    border: 1px solid yellowgreen;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 0 10px;    
}
li:hover ul {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0px);
    -moz-transform:translateY(0px);
    transform:translateY(0px) -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><span>Menu Item 1</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span>Menu Item 2</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><span>Menu Item 4</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Well, it's not quite what I'm trying to achieve. I have the [DEMO](http://wpqa.net/demo.html) here. Please resize the browser to view in mobile for the dropdown menu to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `.menu ul.is-visible` already has "transition" property inherited from `.menu ul`, so you don't have to set it once again.
Secondly, try setting `top` property of `.menu ul.is-visible` to 50px, but with no transition on it (so you can't use `transition: all t`, but e.g. `transition: transform t`)

EDIT: If you could put your code on jsFiddle, I would be very pleased.

UPDATE:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/silveraven/sy4w2/1/)

I've managed to fix this by putting copy of `.menu ul` into new `div.menu` element that's placed before `.header` and both are placed in new `header.nav-header`. It works, but I believe it could be done easier.

Comment: Well, setting the top: 50px will make the menu drop 50px from the header and yes, the other transition property is redundant. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can also try playing with z-indexes of `.header` and `ul` elements to make sure that `ul` will be covered by `.header`.

Comment: No luck on z-indexes. I'll try to see if could use jsFiddle. Thanks for advice though.

Comment: I assume you set z-index on `.menu ul`?

EDIT: Forget it. I forgot its default is 0.

Comment: yes, on .menu ul as well as .header. Still it slides out from the top. I'm sure there is a way; I just don't know how.

Comment: I'll wait for your fiddle ;) It will be much easier to develop it with your code.

Comment: For some reasons, I couldn't get the JS to work in fiddle. I guess I need to upload it to a demo site then..

Comment: Hi, here is the [demo](http://wpqa.net/demo.html). Care to take a look at the code and advise. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thanks, my friend. But your demo pushes the visible menu 50px down when it is open. Initially, I thought it was a simple tweak of X or Y coordinate.... I guess it was not :(

Answer (score -1):

Can't comment yet, but did you try putting 100px instead of 50px in here:

```
-webkit-transform:translateY(50px);
        -moz-transform:translateY(50px);
        transform:translateY(50px)
```

Let me know how it goes, I will investigate to remember how to do it! Long time since I don't use that!

**UPDATE:**

Try this:

```
.menu ul {
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);
        -moz-transform:translateY(-100%);
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```

Setting top to 50px, should move the menu 50px from the top, so it would start scrolling down from the bottom of the header.

If not, try it with jQuery.
Set the menu where you want it to be when it fully scrolls down, and then hide it with `hide()`.
Then in a easy `click()` function u set the efect that you want it to have (fadeIn, scroll, whatever) and you show it with a `show()`.

If you need more detailed jQuery code tell me and I write it for you. Good Luck! ;)

**UPDATE2:**

I did a Fiddle example with jQuery (very basic):

http://jsfiddle.net/3DvVL/1/

The speed of the jQuery effect is set to 800, you can modify it. Same with the effect itself. Also the button I took was for quick demonstration, you can take whatever you want, as long as you point it through name, ID or class in the jQuery.

Comment: I did but the menu will drop 50px further from the bottom of the header.

Comment: Then try with a top: -50px; and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: No, that doesn't work as the visible menu will cover the header. Thanks for the tip too!

Comment: Oh, hmm.. If the menu is dropping from the top of the header, and you want it to drop from the bottom of the header... Try put a top:50px; so the mechanism of dropping is the same but it would do it 50px lower.

Comment: Did you consider doing this in jQuery? It would be easy. Well, anyhow, let us know how is it going! Good luck!

Comment: Updated my initial answer.

Comment: Nope, setting the top:50px will cover the header completely. Anyway, I did a demo here [link](http://wpqa.net/demo.html). Mind if you take a look at it.

Comment: I'll take a look at it. By the way, put ';' after 'z-index:2' in the '.header' CSS code.

Comment: Friend, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3DvVL/1/

Maybe change the fadeOut and fadeIn effects for dropdown, scroll, or whatever. If you need more help just tell me.

Comment: Thanks for everything, my friend. Appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: No problem, tell me if it was helpful for you and if it made it work, even if it is with jQuery and not CSS3. Is just that I feel that with jQuery you have more control over the desired effect and more options to play with. Good Luck! ;)